# Как узнать имя приложения

Tags: c#

Для начала определимся с терминами в данном контексте, на примере браузера Google Chrome.

Имя процесса: **chrome**.exe
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имя приложения: **Google Chrome (32 bit)**

[image]

Мне нужно узнать именно имя приложения, так как оно почти всегда отличается.

Comment: Вам нужно узнать имя вашего приложения?

Comment: @Bezarius, в идеале вообще любого, но отвечая на Ваш вопрос - нет, не моего.

Comment: И как я понимаю, в качестве идентификатора искомого приложения вы хотите использовать имя процесса, верно?

Comment: @Bezarius, да, это неплохой вариант.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возьмите за основу этот пример:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management.Instrumentation;

namespace getAllProcessID
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myID = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            var query = string.Format("SELECT ParentProcessId FROM Win32_Process");// WHERE ProcessId = {0}", myID);
            var search = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", query);
            var results = search.Get().GetEnumerator();

            if (!results.MoveNext())
                throw new Exception("Huh?");

            var queryObj = results.Current;
            uint parentId = (uint)queryObj["ParentProcessId"];

            foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p.MainWindowTitle.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(p.MainWindowHandle.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(p.PrivateMemorySize64.ToString());
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В упор не видел свойство MainWindowHandle, спасибо большое)